# Heap sort not working as expected

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I'm trying to implement heap sort using the CLRS book. My code is:

```
private void maxHeapify(int[] input, int i) {
    int l = left(i);
    int r = right(i);
    int largest;

    if(l <= heapSize && input[l] > input[i]) {
        largest = l;
    } else {
        largest = i;
    }

    if(r <= heapSize && input[r] > input[largest]) {
        largest = r;
    }

    if(largest != i) {
        swap(input, i, largest);
        maxHeapify(input, largest);
    }
}

private void buildMaxHeap(int[] input) {
    heapSize = input.length;
    for(int i = (input.length-1)/2; i >= 0; i--) {
        maxHeapify(input, i);
    }
}

public void heapSort(int[] input) {
    buildMaxHeap(input);

    for(int i = input.length-1; i > 0; i--) {
        swap(input, 0, i);
        heapSize--;
        maxHeapify(input, 0);
    }
}
```

For an input of `{1, 5, 3, 7, 2, 0, 6, 2}`, I'm getting the answer as `7 3 0 6 2 5 1 2`. Why is this happening? I'm guessing it has something to do with the line `for(int i = (input.length-1)/2; i >= 0; i--)` but I can't put my finger on it.

Comment: What are your left and right functions (sometimes people differ in whether they start indexing at 0 or 1)?

Comment: `left(i)` returns `2i` and `right(i)` returns `2i+1`

Comment: You are right, fixing `left(i)` and `right(i)` seemed to have fixed it.